# No more than a number of the same string name in the same array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, oop, if-statement

The problem I have encountered is as follows: I have created 10 row outputs representing docking spaces for ships.

But the dock can accommodate two sizes of ship; cargo and container. The rows are made up of 5 small and 5 medium. A cargo ship (small) can berth in any available space. A container ship (medium) can berth in the medium space, but not in small spaces.

So if I enter shipName and Container for example it searches the array making sure there is less than 5 Container's so it can dock i.e. save in the array. Can you help?
Here's my dock method:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private static Ship[] dock1 = new Ship[10];

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    while(true) {

        System.out.println("Choose an option: 1-3");
        System.out.println("1. Dock");
        System.out.println("2. Undock");
        System.out.println("3. Status");

        int menu = scan.nextInt();
            switch (menu) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("1. Dock");
                    dock();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("2. Undock");
                    undock();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("3. Status");
                    printArray();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("4. Exit");
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    System.out.println("No such option");
                    break;
            }
        }
}

public static void dock() {

    int dockCapacity = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter ship's name: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter ship's size: ");
    String size = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the ships dock:");
    //search for 5 small 3 med 2 large

 //    if what they entered equals shipSize more than 5 than cannot dock.
    for(int i = 1; i < dock1.length; i++) {
        if (dock1[i].getShipSize().equals(size)) {
            System.out.print(dock1[i].getShipSize());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Couldn't dock");
        }
    }
    //Check if the dock number is valid
    int i = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
    if (i >= 0 && i < 10 && dock1[i] == null){
        //Add ship to the dock
        dock1[i] = new Ship(name, size);
        System.out.println("Ship has been docked");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Couldn't dock");
    }
   // printArray();
}

public static void undock(){

    System.out.println("Status of ships: ");
    printArray();
    System.out.println("Enter ship's name to undock: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    for(int i = 1; i < dock1.length; i++){
    if(dock1[i] != null && dock1[i].getShipName().equals(name)){
        dock1[i] = null;
        System.out.println("Ship removed");
        break;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Ship not docked here");
    }
    }

}

public static void printArray() {

    System.out.println("Docks:");

    for(int i = 0; i < dock1.length; i++)
    {
        if(dock1[i] == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + " is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + ": " + dock1[i].getShipName() + " " + dock1[i].getShipSize());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Ship class

```
public class Ship {

private String shipName;
private  String shipSize;

public String getShipName() {
    return shipName;
}

public void setShipName(String shipName) {
    this.shipName = shipName;
}

public String getShipSize() {
    return shipSize;
}

public void setShipSize(String shipSize) {
    this.shipSize = shipSize;
}

public Ship(String shipName, String shipSize) {
    this.shipName = shipName;
    this.shipSize = shipSize;
}
}
```

Comment: First, could you please describe the problem. What does not work as expected? Secondly, could you please provide us with the complete code? To help you, we need to see the Ship class and we need to know what the `dock1` variable is.

Comment: @GeorgMuehlenberg The problem is that I do not know how to code it so that when I enter the shipSize it checks that there is only a certain amount of the size entered and can then save to the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to change the Ship class like this. It adds a ShipSize enum and makes it much easier to parse the ship size from string and compare ship sizes. Also, I added a `isCargo` and `isContainer` method.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Ship {

    private String shipName;
    private ShipSize shipSize;
    public Ship(String shipName, ShipSize shipSize) {
        this.shipName = shipName;
        this.shipSize = shipSize;
    }

    public String getShipName() {
        return shipName;
    }

    public void setShipName(String shipName) {
        this.shipName = shipName;
    }

    public ShipSize getShipSize() {
        return shipSize;
    }

    public void setShipSize(ShipSize shipSize) {
        this.shipSize = shipSize;
    }

    public boolean isCargo() {
        return shipSize == ShipSize.CARGO;
    }

    public boolean isContainer() {
        return shipSize == ShipSize.CONTAINER;
    }

    public enum ShipSize {
        CARGO,
        CONTAINER;

        public static ShipSize of(String size) {
            return Arrays.stream(ShipSize.values()).filter(enumSize -> enumSize.name().equalsIgnoreCase(size)).findAny().orElse(null);
        }
    }
}
```

I also modified your main class so it does what you want. I added some parsing and checks for the numbers, added an initialize method for the docks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Dock[] dock1 = new Dock[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        initializeDock();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        while(true) {

            System.out.println("Choose an option: 1-3");
            System.out.println("1. Dock");
            System.out.println("2. Undock");
            System.out.println("3. Status");

            int menu = scan.nextInt();
            switch (menu) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("1. Dock");
                    dock();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("2. Undock");
                    undock();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("3. Status");
                    printArray();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("4. Exit");
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    System.out.println("No such option");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void initializeDock() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            dock1[i] = new Dock(Ship.ShipSize.CARGO);
        }
        for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
            dock1[i] = new Dock(Ship.ShipSize.CONTAINER);
        }
    }

    public static void dock() {

        int dockCapacity = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter ship's name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();

        Ship.ShipSize size = null;
        while(size == null) {
            System.out.println("Enter ship's size: ");
            String stringSize = scan.nextLine();
            size = Ship.ShipSize.of(stringSize);
            if (size == null) {
                System.out.println("Could not read ship size. Only cargo and container are allowed.");
            }
        }

        // check that ship fits into any dock
        if (size == Ship.ShipSize.CONTAINER) {
            long numberOfContainerShips = Arrays.stream(dock1).map(Dock::getDockedShip).filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(Ship::isContainer).count();
            if (numberOfContainerShips >= 5) {
                System.out.println("No place for a ship that large. Aborting.");
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Enter the ships dock:");
        Integer dockNumber = null;
        while(dockNumber == null) {
            dockNumber = scan.nextInt();
            if (dockNumber < 0 || dockNumber > dock1.length - 1) {
                System.out.println("Illegal dock number. Only numbers between 0 and " + dock1.length + " are allowed.");
                dockNumber = null;
            }
        }

        Dock dock = dock1[dockNumber];
        if (dock.getDockedShip() != null) {
            System.out.println("Dock reserved - couldn't dock");
            return;
        }
        if (dock.getSupportedSize() == Ship.ShipSize.CARGO && size == Ship.ShipSize.CONTAINER) {
            System.out.println("Dock too small - couldn't dock");
            return;
        }

        dock.setDockedShip(new Ship(name, size));
    }

    public static void undock(){

        System.out.println("Status of ships: ");
        printArray();
        System.out.println("Enter ship's name to undock: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        for(int i = 1; i < dock1.length; i++){
            if(dock1[i].getDockedShip() != null && dock1[i].getDockedShip().getShipName().equals(name)){
                dock1[i] = null;
                System.out.println("Ship removed");
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Ship not docked here");
            }
        }

    }

    public static void printArray() {

        System.out.println("Docks:");

        for(int i = 0; i < dock1.length; i++)
        {
            if(dock1[i].getDockedShip() == null)
            {
                System.out.println("Dock " + i + " is empty. Size: " + dock1[i].getSupportedSize().name().toLowerCase());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Dock " + i + ": " + dock1[i].getDockedShip().getShipName() + " " + dock1[i].getDockedShip().getShipSize().name().toLowerCase());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also added a Dock class. It works fine.

```
public class Dock {

    private Ship.ShipSize supportedSize;
    private Ship dockedShip = null;

    public Dock(Ship.ShipSize supportedSize) {
        this.supportedSize = supportedSize;
    }

    public Ship.ShipSize getSupportedSize() {
        return supportedSize;
    }

    public void setSupportedSize(Ship.ShipSize supportedSize) {
        this.supportedSize = supportedSize;
    }

    public Ship getDockedShip() {
        return dockedShip;
    }

    public void setDockedShip(Ship dockedShip) {
        this.dockedShip = dockedShip;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your in depth answer you have helped me greatly. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. But there is a small flaw in the code. In the `undock()`-method, you need to `setDockedShip(null)`. Good luck in your further learning Java.